# How do I uninstall Korg audio drivers from a Mac

Tags: audio

I'm trying to get Korg's DS DAC 100m working on my son's Mac Book. Our first try was to just plug it in, but the Mac did not recognise it as a sound device. Then we downloaded the driver software from http://www.korg.com/us/support/download/software/0/529/2584/ and ran the driver installer. Now when we plug in the DAC to his Mac the Mac hangs for a few seconds and then reboots. I know how to uninstall drivers on a PC, and I know how to uninstall apps on a Mac, but I cannot see how to uninstall a failing sound driver from a Mac. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Typical - no sooner have I posted the question than we realise that the download also contains an uninstaller.

But, according to Korg's [2015.11.09 news](http://www.korg.com/us/news/2015/110902/)

> We can inform you today that DS-DAC-100 and DS-DAC-100m are not compatible with El Capitan and advise you not to update your operating system until compatible versions has been released.

So we're stuffed anyway.

Comment: I've asked when the driver will be compatible on [the Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7398024?start=0&tstart=0) and [a Korg forum](http://www.korgforums.com/forum/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=672097) but no luck yet

Comment: Beta's out: http://www.korg.com/us/news/2016/032202/